# assign jquery variable to input

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass jquery variable value to input text. I tried the below and getting message "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable". How to send jquery variable value to input box?

//Input is as below

```
<input  type="hidden" id="rowValues" value="" name="rowValues">
```

//jquery is as below. rowData variable value should be passed to input

```
 var rowData = JSON.stringify(rows); ; 

$("#rowValues").val() = rowData;
```

Comment: Read http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

do:

```
$("#rowValues").val(rowData);
```

Answer (score 5):

You use `$("#rowValues").val()` when you want to get data from

```
 var data = $("#rowValues").val();
```

But for assigning data to input

```
 $("#rowValues").val(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 $("#rowValues").val(rowData);
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the value you pass the parameter to the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function.

```
$("#rowValues").val(rowData);
```

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
$("#rowValues").val(rowData);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var rowData = JSON.stringify(rows);
$("#rowValues").val(rowData);
```